# How to populate dropdown box with indices list

Tags: c#, winforms, elasticsearch, nest

Was hoping this could be a quick answer.  New to C# and NEST (as is probably obvious from my previous posts).

I am using NEST to query my ES instance and have built a small winform application to help accomplish the task.  I would like to have one of the comboboxes on my winform populate dynamically with the names of the indices from my cluster.

So far I have used:

```
var node = new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxx");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var myindexes = client.CatIndices();
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to populate the values of my combobox with the values store in "myindexes"

I have tried

```
combobox1.value = myindexes.ToList();
```

but can't see to figure out how to go one level deeper.

I know it is a simple question, but I would really appreciate the help if somebody could spare a few moments.

Thanks very much for the help as always!

Mick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing myindexes is an object that implement `IList` or an `Array`. You can use either of these options:

[ComboBox.DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = myindexes;
```

[ComboBox.Items.AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(myindexes.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

**Note:**

- The text that will be shown for items in `ComboBox` is the result of `ToString` method.
- If you are showing a complex object, using `DataSource` way, you can set [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) to one of properties of your complex object to show in `ComboBox`.
- The object that you want to set to `DataSource` property, should be an object that implements the `IList` interface or an `Array`. If it's not, you should first convert it to the expected mentioned types.

Comment: I tried `myindexes.ToList()` but got "ICatResponse<CatIndicesRecord>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'ICatResponse<CatIndicesRecord>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Thank  you Reza.  I am using `system.Linq'.  `ICatResponse<CatIndicesRecord>' is the variable type generated by the `CatIndices` method available in the NEST package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100619/discussion-between-irishmickeyward-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 0):

you may use [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = myindexes.ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
```